# Do not have pip for my QGIS Python.

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, osgeo4w

I want to install gsutil onto my QGIS's version of python.

Most tutorials say I should be able use the pip/pip3 command.

When I run OSGeo4WShell, it does not have the pip command available. How can I download pip for my QGIS's python?

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure pip/pip3 is installed through the OSGeo4W installer.

It is an option that can be chosen through the advanced install:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check this, it may help you:

https://github.com/pypa/get-pip

1. Curl pip via the OSGEO shell
2. Call pip and install packages/modules for Python through pip