# Import Qgis.core in Spyder

Tags: qgis, python, osgeo4w, spyder

I'm currently trying to translate the tasks I performed using Qgis (3.16.5) into a Python (Spyder) script, such that I will be able to perform these tasks on multiple files more easily.

However, I'm experiencing difficulties importing Qgis into Spyder. First, I received an error. After looking on internet, I found many topics related to this and I tried most of them.

Most of them were related to changing the PYTHONPATH and PATHs. I ended up with the script below:
'''

```
@echo off
  SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64
  call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat
  call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\apps\grass\grass78\etc\env.bat
  @echo off
  path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
  path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass78\lib

  set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;
  set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages
  cmd.exe
```

However, I now get a new error: "DLL load failed while importing _core: Cannot find procedure" and still cannot import qgis.core. I tried this code both with OSGeo4W64 and with a Qgis version downloaded without OSGeo4W64.

How can I import the Qgis.core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm somewhat confused that you have a recent QGIS (3.16.5), but that you're starting a Python 2.7? QGIS 3 uses Python 3, not 2.7 and it won't work.

At any rate, in your QGIS installation, you'll find some batch files, in my case it's this one `c:\Program Files\QGIS 3.18\bin\py3_env.bat` and `python-qgis.bat`.

So open your command line, and run:

```
cd c:\Program Files\QGIS 3.18\bin
CALL py3_env.bat
CALL python-qgis.bat
```

This'll start the QGIS interpreter, I can succesfully import `qgis.core` here.

```
c:\Program Files\QGIS 3.18\bin>python
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import qgis.core
>>> exit()
```

You can check whether it's starting the right python now by e.g. running:

```
where python
```

This should return the QGIS python as its first entry:

```
c:\Program Files\QGIS 3.18\apps\Python3.7\python.exe
```

Now, you could try starting Spyder (just run `spyder` in the command line). However, it has to be installed **for this QGIS Python interpreter speficically**. I think the default QGIS installation by default comes with pip, if you install via OSGeo4W, see: [Do not have pip for my QGIS Python.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303939/do-not-have-pip-for-my-qgis-python)

Note, however, that this is somewhat hap-hazard: QGIS and Spyder have a shared dependency in (Py)Qt and they might e.g. demand different versions.

If you run into trouble, you could try using a (non-Qt) editor/IDE like Visual Studio Code (again, probably start it after setting all the environmental variables right with the batch files mentioned above), or possibly something from jupyter.