# Is it possible to use PyQGIS functions from a Python IDE?

Tags: python, pyqgis-3

I have started to use PyQGIS but sometimes processes take too long.

So, I want to know if is it possible to use PyQGIS functions directly from a Python IDE (Now I use Jupyter notebooks but it wouldn't be a problem to use PyCharm, Spyder or another one).

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins/ide_debugging.html

Comment: sure, but it won't be any faster

Comment: Answer below should work fine for PyCharm or VSCode, but if you prefer Spyder, I gave a brief answer on this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396832/import-qgis-core-in-spyder/397499#397499
As noted, it won't make Python run any faster.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running Python outside of QGIS - (ImportError: No module named qgis.core)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141990/running-python-outside-of-qgis-importerror-no-module-named-qgis-core)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I keep this pyQGIS.cmd file around to make my PyCharm QGIS aware:

```
@echo off

SET QGIS_ROOT=C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.2
SET QT_DIR=qt5
SET GRASS_DIR=grass78
SET PYTHON_DIR=Python39

call "%QGIS_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"

call "%QGIS_ROOT%\apps\grass\%GRASS_DIR%\etc\env.bat"


@echo off


path %PATH%;%QGIS_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin

path %PATH%;%QGIS_ROOT%\apps\grass\%GRASS_DIR%\lib

path %PATH%;%QGIS_ROOT%\apps\%QT_DIR%\bin

path %PATH%;%QGIS_ROOT%\apps\%PYTHON_DIR%\Scripts


set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%QGIS_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python

set PYTHONHOME=%QGIS_ROOT%\apps\%PYTHON_DIR%


start "PyQGIS" /B "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.3.2\bin\pycharm64.exe"
```

You will have to adjust the paths to make it work on your system and update them when you update QGIS.

Just add a shortcut pointing to it to `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` and you can call it from the start menu.

Edit:

Original source: https://silverspringenergy.com/using-pycharm-as-an-ide-for-qgis-3-plugin-development-2/