# PyQGIS not working with PyCharm on Windows, only Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, python, ubuntu, windows, pycharm

I can't make PyCharm work with PyQGIS on Windows.
On Ubuntu I did the following to make it work:

- Installed QGIS
- Installed PyCharm
- New project with existing interpreter

  - System Interpreter --> usr/bin/python3.8
- Add QGIS Python folder path to interpreter path: /usr/share/qgis/python
  And it works.

On Windows I tried methods equivalent to this, and also the QGIS interpreter (qgis/bin/python3.exe and also qgis/apps/python37/python.exe)
I tried to use the following (two) batch file for starting PyCharm:

```
@echo off
SET PYCHARM="C:\Users\Anderle Dani\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\211.7628.24\bin\pycharm64.exe"
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\qt5_env.bat
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\py3_env.bat
@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\plugins
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\python;%PYTHONPATH%

start "PyCharm aware of Quantum GIS" /B %PYCHARM% %*
```

And:

```
@echo off

call “C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16”\bin\o4w_env.bat

call “C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\apps\grass\grass78”\etc\env.bat

@echo off

path %PATH%;C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\apps\qgis-ltr\bin

path %PATH%;C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\apps\grass\grass78\lib

path %PATH%;C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\apps\Qt5\bin

path %PATH%;C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\apps\Python37\Scripts

set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\apps\qgis-ltr\python

set PYTHONHOME=C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\apps\Python37

set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\apps\qgis-ltr\qtplugins;C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\apps\Qt5\plugins

SET PYCHARM="C:\Users\Anderle Dani\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\211.7628.24\bin\pycharm64.exe" 

 

start "PyCharm aware of QGIS" /B %PYCHARM% %*
```

But PyCharm still gives errors as seen on these screenshots:
[image: pycharm errors]

On Ubuntu it did the same until I tried to set venv interpreter instead of system interpreter, but on Windows it doesn't work.

Comment: Does it work outside of PyCharm? See e.g. the answer I posted here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396832/import-qgis-core-in-spyder/397499#397499

Comment: I can run scripts inside qgis but in pycharm it happens like you can see in my post